# Error while doing ndk-build- "unknown type name 'time_t' "

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have tried HelloWorld app using JNI and it is working fine. Then I modified it to have a header file: 
Contents of custom_header.h are

```
#include<time.h>
struct my_struct
{
   struct timeval tmvl;
};
```

Contents of HelloJNI.c are

```
#include "include/custom_header.h"
<<other code>>
```

I am having following error when I did "ndk-build" in /home/sattu/workspace_jni/AndroidHelloJNI/jni directory

```
In file included from /home/sattu/workspace_jni/AndroidHelloJNI/jni/include/custom_header.h:1:0,
                 from /home/sattu/workspace_jni/AndroidHelloJNI/jni/HelloJNI.c:4:
/home/sattu/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-15/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/time.h:20:2: error: unknown type name 'time_t'
/home/sattu/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-15/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/time.h:26:2: error: unknown type name 'time_t'
/home/sattu/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-15/arch-arm/usr/include/linux/time.h:27:2: error: unknown type name 'suseconds_t'
```

What would be missing out?

Comment: try replacing #include<time.h> with #include <sys/time.h>

Comment: Thanks, it is working. Before it was referring to "linux/time.h".